# Bit operators C++

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitwise-xor

Can someone explain to me how this function works? I understand the drop the lowest set of a bit of `x` part which is the 5th line but I don't understand the assignment `result ^= 1;`  Shouldn't result be counting 0 and 1 when deciding parity of a word?

```
short Parity_of_word(unsigned long long x) {
    short result = 0;
    while(x) {
        result ^= 1;
        x &= (x-1);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: `^= 1` just toggles the least significant bit. Here it works the same as if you declared `bool result = false;` instead, and replaced `result ^= 1;` with `result = !result;`.

Comment: it actually does iterate through 1 bits by removing them by sustraction and &, there is similar approach for Hamming code (popcount, count of 1 bits). For parity bit there is a faster way actually. ^=1 is XoR 1

Comment: @dxiv but if the result is always false then how does the function keep track of all the 1s and 0s in the word?

Comment: @galo2324 do you understand what ! and ^ do? Not false is true. 1 xor 1 = 0.

Comment: @galo2324 It's *not* always false. It alternates between `0, 1, 0, 1 ...` or `false, true, false, true, ...` with each bit you count.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie so the function iterates through the word and each time it deletes the lowest bit but where is that record for how many 1s was counted is kept?

Comment: @galo2324 that'd be popcount and you would need a counter. Parity is 1 or 0, you dont need a counter. But if you look in wiki , you'll find algo that doesn't use extra flag and is faster by N operations, it works such way , that parity bit would be the least significant one in x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
result ^= 1;
```

changes `result` between 0 and 1, repeatedly. So, the question is: How many time will this be done?

```
x&=(x-1);
```

is a hacky way to do "remove the last bit from x". To see it, imagine x is

```
0101000110
```

removing one will make it:

```
0101000101
```

(all the 0 in the end became 1, and the first 1 became 0). Once you `and` both values together:

```
0101000100
```

Tada, one less `1`. So, the while loop will execute just as many times as there are `1`s in `x`. And it will flip `result` accordingly.